# Where are the version choices for android?

Tags: android

In the android tutorials, I end up with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

and would prefer to lock the version for consistency sake, but apparently they are not on the maven repo.  I try to go to https://bintray.com/android but do not see a way to search.

EDIT: I do not want documentation.  I want a list like in the old days of exact version so we know 100% that the version exists (and may see some that the docs do not mention). As a concrete example, webpieces has this list of versions (this list is very exact).

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webpieces/http-webserver/

Where do I search and see the listing of com.android.support items and then click on each and see their versions?

ps.  I tried 26.0.0 and '26.0.0 Release' and neither work.  I get the following.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        file:/Users/dhiller/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
  >        file:/Users/dhiller/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
  >        file:/Library/Workflow/phonetag/android/PhoneTag/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   Could not find com.android.support:design:26.0.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        file:/Users/dhiller/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.pom
  >        file:/Users/dhiller/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar
  >        file:/Library/Workflow/phonetag/android/PhoneTag/sdk-manager/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar

Below, they say add a maven repo now, but that doesn't quite make sense.  How did my generated project with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+' work just fine?  It somehow downloaded from the jcenter repo?

Comment: `Where do I search and see the listing of com.android.support items` try google. If you search google for "the listing of com.android.support items", you get a bunch of links that give you exactly this information

Comment: I did and adding 26.0.0 NOR 26.0.0 Release in the gradle file works.  none of that works so my question still stands though I can add the error I guess.

Comment: That's fair, but your question is where to find the versions, not how to fix the error

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes, sorry, I want to find the 'exact' versions!!!  ie. for example, for webpieces, it's easy http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webpieces/http-webserver/  Documentation is not the best for finding exact released versions and can be wrong.  So I still want the list of versions but I want the directory of the maven repo so I can look there without looking at stale documentation (if possible).

Comment: @TimCastelijns ps. thanks, I will clarify my question

Answer (score 5):

You can check the official [Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0) for details about the most recent Support Library package releases.

[image]

For earlier releases, see the [Support Library Revisions Archive](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html)

[image]

To use those support repositories, Make sure to includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Later, Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example, to add the v4 core-utils library, add the following lines:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It helps everyone.

Comment: so how do I edit the build.gradle file?  I tried adding 26.0.0 and that does not work.

Comment: @prokash sarkar I added to the answer as your solution does not give me what I need to type into the build.gradle file.  I typed in what you list and it still does not work.

Comment: @DeanHiller Did you added the maven section with "https://maven.google.com" endpoint in build.gradle?

Comment: @ProkashSarkar :( you would think the Android Studio would have generated that for me :(.  IN FACT, how is my generated project even working?  after all, it seems to have gotten something from jcenter.  Lastly, maven repos usually have a directory with the files so you can read the 'exact' version.  I can't seem to find that and that is WAY more preferable than some documentation.  After all, I still do not know what version number to type in and have to 'guess' (not very optimal).  For example, one can look at this maven repo http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webpieces/http-webserver/

Comment: @ProkashSarkar sorry, I clarified my question.   I was used to people answering with exact maven links in the past.  with the info from the comment.